# Stuck on "Stem Remover" assignment

Tags: java

I have an assignment for school and need a bit of help. Our assignment is "Grade: N/A
View Grade Information. Opens a dialogue
Due: Tuesday, November 20, 2018 at 11:59 pm
In Eclipse, create a static method toggleStem that takes two arguments, both Strings. If the second argument begins with the first argument, then the method returns the second argument with that "stem" removed. On the other hand, if the second argument does not begin with the first argument, the method returns the result of attaching the first argument to the front of the second. For example, if the arguments are:

"side" and "sideways",

then the static method should return the String "ways", and if the arguments are

"side" and "kick",

it should return the String "sidekick".

Call the method in the program. Print out the result."

My code (that isn't working as i intended, Instead of removing the stem before adding it just adds the two words in the return which is there incase the two words dont share a stem) is:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String m = combine("side", "sideways");
    System.out.print(m);
 }
 public static String combine(String a, String b){
     int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= a.length(); i++){
        if (!(i <= b.length())){
            if (a.substring(0, i) == b.substring(0, i)){
                ans = i;
            }
        }else{
            if (ans == 0){
                return a+b;
            }else{
                return a + b.substring(0, ans);
            }
        }
    } return a+b;
 }

}
```

Thank you for your time and answers

Edit: clarifying what i mean by "not working"

Comment: As always: Please  define "not working"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use == operator when comparing strings in java like in here `a.substring(0, i) == b.substring(0, i)` It compares memory references, not actual values. Instead use String.equals(String) method.
Your assignment is pretty simple. You need to find out if substring created from second argument (characters 0 to length of first argument) equals the first argument. If so then return substring created from second argument (characters not used during the first check). Otherwise just return first and second concatenated. Of course there is one special case when you know for sure that first argument isn't part of the second one (do you know when this happens?)
I'm not going to post final program here, but I'll give you methods you'll need to use (all of them are from String class):

```
length()
substring() (both versions: one and two arguments)
equals()
+ operator to concatenate strings
```

Think about it for a while, if you still got problems hit me up.